# Building python extensions in-place and installing in one shot

Tags: python, distutils

In order to install a python package we do

```
python setup.py install
```

or if we have Cython modules, to build them in-place, we do

```
python build_ext --inplace
```

Is there a way to do both at the same time?  This is useful for me so that I can do source-level debugging on the local files, while also keeping my site-packages up to date for a GUI program that uses the site-packages code.

Typically I hack my setup.py file to have something like this in the header:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
#    sys.argv += ['build_ext','--inplace']
    sys.argv += ['build','install']
```

And then I uncomment the one I want and comment out the other one.  It's ugly, but that way I can run the setup.py script (in Scite or Eclipse) without having to resort to the console.  So I would ideally like to use a command like

```
sys.argv += ['build_ext','--inplace','install']
```

but those semantics don't work and python gets angry.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work? (I can't test right now.)

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace install
```

Comment: Nope - it doesn't copy the .pyd files generated in the build_ext step - only the .py files get copied

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me; the install command calls build, which calls build_ext, and distutils takes care to merge all options and run one command once, so an explicit option to build_ext on the command line should be used when the install command runs build_ext implicitly.  Maybe the code that tracks what files are created and should be copied by install has a bug.